# Find value from Dictionary where value property is null using C# LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

In the below code, the dictionary will have a lot of Person data, with some missing information about Name property. I need to get the list of Person **ID**s, where the **Name** property is Null or Empty.

Note: I am expecting List for the missing Names

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Age {get; set;}
}  

public class Persons
{
   private Dictionary<int, Person> m_dic =new Dictionary<int, Person>();
   public Dictionary<int, Person> Data 
   {
       get { return m_dic; }
   }

   public void AddData()
   {
       //Code to fill m_dic 
       m_dic.Add(1, new Person() {101, "John", 30 });
       m_dic.Add(2, new Person() {102, "", 40 });
       m_dic.Add(3, new Person() {103, "Peter", 20 });
       m_dic.Add(4, new Person() {104, "", 46});
   }

   public List<int> FindData()
   {
       var list = from p in m_dic
                  where p.Value.Name == Null
                  select new { p.value.Id };
       return list;
   }
}
```

So the output will have List with values like 102, 104. Need to improve the LINQ query. Can someone help?

Comment: What's the issue you are facing? What's the improvement you are looking for?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. That would be the issue you're facing first.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`.Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-5.0) clause to filter dictionary elements based on condition and use [`.Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-5.0) to get list of `Ids`,

```
var result = m_dic
      .Where(x => String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Value.Name))  //Filter where name is null or empty
      .Select(y => y.Value.Id)  //Get only Ids
      .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You should be check for `where string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Value.Name)` instead of `where p.Value.Name == Null`. So it will handle `null` value as well as blank `""`.
2. Update `select` statement and not use `new { ... }` because it will create `IEnumerable<Object>` not `IEnumerable<int>`. You can just use `select p.Value.Id` to return list of `id`s.
3. In return statement use `return list.ToList();` so it will convert `IEnumerable<int>` to `List<int>`.

Updated function will be like below.

```
public static List<int> FindData()
{
     var list = from p in m_dic
              where string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Value.Name)
              select p.Value.Id;
     return list.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use Lambda expression in your find function. I'm rewriting your function with lambda.

```
public List<int> FindData()
{
    var list = m_dic.Where(x => x.Value.Name.Equals("")).Select(x => x.Value.Id).ToList();
    return list;
}
```

You'll get your desired result.

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP asked for.

Comment: But on positive side this code does not produce invalid results either - it will simply NRE for cases OP claims to cares about, so it's not *that* bad :)